# Multiply two equal-sized list and sum the result (dot product)

Tags: python

I have two list which are of the same size and I want to multiply the two data in the same index position of the two list and get the sum of the new list.

```
>>> left = range(10)  
>>> right = range(10, 20)  
>>> sum([left[i]*right[i] for i in xrange(len(left))]) # output 735
```

I want to know if there's a more simple way to do such an operation without using non-standard python libraries.

Comment: `sum(a*b for a, b in zip(left, right))` is probably most common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about this

```
right = range(10, 20)                                                       
left = range(10)   
sum(x*y for x, y in zip(left, right))
735
```

Or for those functionally inclined ;-)

```
from operator import mul
from itertools import starmap, izip
sum(starmap(mul, izip(left, right)))
735
```

Comment: The first is more pythonic and the second gives me some thought about functional programming in Python. Thank you :D